# Spectrum of a Kronecker sum of an operator with itself

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization, kronecker-product

Let $A$ be an arbitrary diagonalizable square matrix. Consider $A \oplus A = A \otimes I + I \otimes A$ that is a Kronecker sum of $A$ with itself ($I$ is of the same size as $A$ here). I want to express the eigenvectors of $A \oplus A$ through the eigenvectors of $A$ **explicitly**.

If $A = S_A \cdot D_A \cdot S_A^{-1} $ (eigendecomposition), then the set of right eigenvectors of $A \otimes I$ is, obviously, $S_A \otimes I$, while for $I \otimes A$  it is $I \otimes S_A$. What I also know is that $A \otimes I$, and $I \otimes A$ commute, therefore, they are simultaneously diagonalizable.

How can one express the matrix $S_{A \oplus A}$ that diagonalizes the corresponding matrix through $S_A$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $S_{A \oplus A} = S_A \otimes S_A$. Indeed, we have
$$
S_{A \oplus A}^{-1}(A \oplus A)S_{A \oplus A} =\\
(S_A \otimes S_A)^{-1}(A \otimes I + I \otimes A)(S_A \otimes S_A) =\\
(S_A^{-1} \otimes S_A^{-1})(A \otimes I + I \otimes A)(S_A \otimes S_A) =\\
(S_A^{-1} \otimes S_A^{-1})(A \otimes I)(S_A \otimes S_A) + 
(S_A^{-1} \otimes S_A^{-1})(I \otimes A)(S_A \otimes S_A) =\\
(S_A^{-1}AS_A) \otimes (S_A^{-1}IS_A) + (S_A^{-1}IS_A) \otimes (S_A^{-1}AS_A) =\\
D_A \otimes I + I \otimes D_A.
$$
I will leave it to you to verify that $D_{A \oplus A}:= D_A \otimes I + I \otimes D_A$ is indeed a diagonal matrix.

Comment: Dear Ben Grossmann, nice to see you again, and thank you! Indeed, what you wrote is absolutely correct. What I find interesting is that the eigenvalues of the Kronecker sum is actually the sum of all possible pairs of eigenvalues of the original matrix $A$. It makes a lot of sense provided that one considers some physical problem described by matrix $A$.

Comment: It's particularly nice in light of the relationship between the Kronecker sum, the Kronecker product, and the matrix exponential. In particular, we have
$$
\exp(A \oplus B) = \exp(A) \otimes \exp(B).
$$
In other words, the matrix exponential takes us from a matrix whose eigenvalues are $\lambda_{i} + \lambda_j$ (for all pairs $i,j$) to one whose eigenvalues are of the form $e^{\lambda_i + \lambda_j} = e^{\lambda_i}e^{\lambda_j}$.